# Sonicwall NetExtender drops internet connection on my machine

Tags: centos, vpn

Shortly after connecting to company VPN I get internet drop. I'm connected to VPN but everything else on my machine can't connect. I have tried reinstall it but it keeps dropping my internet connection. I'm on Centos 8 but it happens on Centos 7 too.
Here is the log:

```
03/05/2021 18:50:40.410 [config  info     4203] Compatibility mode: Default
03/05/2021 18:50:42.240 [gui     info     4203] createLogPanel()
03/05/2021 18:50:43.050 [config  info     4203] Loading saved profiles...
03/05/2021 18:50:43.058 [config  info     4203] Loaded profile: -------
03/05/2021 18:50:43.059 [config  info     4203] Loaded profile: --------
03/05/2021 18:50:43.059 [config  info     4203] Done.
03/05/2021 18:51:06.831 [connect info     4203] User:   "-------"
03/05/2021 18:51:06.831 [connect info     4203] Domain: "----------"
03/05/2021 18:51:06.831 [connect info     4203] Server: "------------"
03/05/2021 18:51:06.916 [general notice   4203] Connecting to -------------...
03/05/2021 18:51:06.980 [connect warn     4203] SSL_get_peer_certificate: X509_V_ERR_INVALID_CA
03/05/2021 18:51:06.980 [general notice   4203] Connected.
03/05/2021 18:51:06.980 [general notice   4203] Logging in...
03/05/2021 18:51:09.056 [general notice   4203] Login successful.
03/05/2021 18:51:09.124 [general error    4203] Version header not found
03/05/2021 18:51:09.124 [epc     info     4203] Server don't support EPC check. Just pass EPC check
03/05/2021 18:51:09.366 [general notice   4203] SSL Connection is ready
03/05/2021 18:51:10.369 [general info     4203] Using new PPP frame encoding mechanism
03/05/2021 18:51:10.370 [general info     4203] Using PPP async mode (chosen by server) 
03/05/2021 18:51:10.370 [general info     4203] Connecting tunnel...
03/05/2021 18:51:10.974 [connect info     4300] PPP interface up
03/05/2021 18:51:11.000 [dns     notice   4300] Setting up DNS
03/05/2021 18:51:12.017 [general info     4300] Setting up DNS suffixes
03/05/2021 18:51:12.036 [general info     4313] Monitoring processes:  nx=4203, pppd=4279
03/05/2021 18:51:12.036 [dns     info     4313] Monitoring nameserver: 192.168.3.2
03/05/2021 18:51:12.036 [dns     info     4313] Monitoring nameserver: 192.168.3.3
03/05/2021 18:51:12.036 [dns     info     4313] Monitoring DNS suffix: elranchito.local
03/05/2021 18:51:13.065 [general info     4203] Client IP Address: ---------------
03/05/2021 18:51:13.065 [general info     4203] You now have access to the following 188 remote networks:
03/05/2021 18:51:13.065 [general info     --------------------------------------------------------
                      --------------------------------------------------------
                      --------------------------------------------------------
                      --------------------------------------------------------
                      --------------------------------------------------------
                      --------------------------------------------------------
03/05/2021 18:51:13.070 [general notice   4203] NetExtender connected successfully.
03/05/2021 18:51:13.963 [general info     4203] Saving profiles/preferences...
03/05/2021 18:51:13.963 [general info     4203] Done saving profiles/preferences
```

Comment: Do you mean the VPN still works, and that you have internet access via the VPN? Or that internet access from the local machine not over the VPN is unavailable? Because the latter is reasonable with a full-tunnel VPN.

Comment: Yes, I mean I steal have VPN + citrix but browser does not nor email client.

Comment: I would therefore suspect a full tunnel VPN, and that once the VPN is connected, there would need to be a change to the proxy the browser uses.

Comment: How to configure for example Chrome to use VPN?